# Why does Object, the class, respond to instance methods defined on it?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, instance-methods, class-method

I ran into this behavior earlier today and was hoping somebody could explain why this happens:

```
class Object
  def some_method
  end
end

Object.respond_to?(:some_method) # => true
```

Of course, this doesn't happen with other classes:

```
class Dog
  def some_other_method
  end
end

Dog.respond_to?(:some_other_method) # => false
```

So what gives?

Comment: `class Object` is itself an `Object`. `Object.is_a?(Object)`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yeah, but so is Dog in this case. Everything is_a?(Object). I'm just confused as to why Object specifically would respond to instance methods defined on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens b/c `Object` is a superclass of `Class` itself. So `class Object` is an instance of `Object` (confusing). When you define an instance method on `Dog` you dont cause the same issue b/c the class `Dog` does not appear in the inheritance chain of `Class`

```
Object.instance_of?(Class) # True
Class.is_a?(Object) # True
Class.is_a?(Dog) # False
```